# All time high which is not recent

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to modify script to get all time high date that is not recent.
[image]

Eg: Apple made all time high on

1. 15/10/2021 (last)
2. 10/05/2017 (second last)
   ... and so on ...

The problem is that this script is showing the recently ATH, I want ATH that is atleast a year old. Any help/guidance is appreciated.
I want to use it for ATH breakout (preferable 5-10 years old)

```
indicator('All-Time High/Low', shorttitle='ATH/ATL', overlay=true)

////////////
// INPUTS //

show_ath   = input(true,  "Show All Time High?")
show_atl   = input(false, "Show All Time Low?")
show_table = input(true,  "Show table with stats?")

///////////////
// FUNCTIONS //

// all-time high function
get_all_time_high() =>
    h  = 0.0
    t  = 0
    h := bar_index == 0 ? high : high > h[1] ? high : h[1]
    t := bar_index == 0 ? time : high > h[1] ? time : t[1]
    [h, t]

// all-time low function   
get_all_time_low() =>
    l = 0.0
    t = 0
    l := bar_index == 0 ? low  : low < l[1] ? low  : l[1]
    t := bar_index == 0 ? time : low < l[1] ? time : t[1]
    [l, t]

// getting all-time high/low    
[ath, ath_dt] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', get_all_time_high())
[atl, atl_dt] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', get_all_time_low())

ath_days = math.round((timenow - ath_dt) / 86400000)
atl_days = math.round((timenow - atl_dt) / 86400000)

// plotting
if show_ath
    lATH=line.new(bar_index - 1, ath, bar_index, ath, extend = extend.both, color = color.green)
    line.delete(lATH[1])
    
if show_atl
    lATL=line.new(bar_index - 1, atl, bar_index, atl, extend = extend.both, color = color.red)
    line.delete(lATL[1])

if show_table
    var table ATHtable = table.new(position.bottom_right, 6, 3, frame_color = color.gray, bgcolor = color.gray, border_width = 1, frame_width = 1, border_color = color.white)

    ath_time = str.tostring(year(ath_dt)) + "-" + str.tostring(month(ath_dt)) + "-" + str.tostring(dayofmonth(ath_dt))
    atl_time = str.tostring(year(atl_dt)) + "-" + str.tostring(month(atl_dt)) + "-" + str.tostring(dayofmonth(atl_dt))

    // Header
    table.cell(ATHtable, 0, 0, "",         bgcolor = #cccccc)
    table.cell(ATHtable, 1, 0, "When?",    bgcolor = #cccccc)
    table.cell(ATHtable, 2, 0, "Days ago", bgcolor = #cccccc)
    table.cell(ATHtable, 3, 0, "Price",    bgcolor = #cccccc)
    table.cell(ATHtable, 4, 0, "% away",   bgcolor = #cccccc)
    table.cell(ATHtable, 5, 0, "$ away",   bgcolor = #cccccc)
    
    if (show_ath)
        // ATH
        table.cell(ATHtable, 0, 1, "ATH",                                                  bgcolor = #cccccc)
        table.cell(ATHtable, 1, 1, ath_time,                                               bgcolor = color.new(color.green, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 2, 1, str.tostring(ath_days),                                 bgcolor = color.new(color.green, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 3, 1, str.tostring(ath, format.mintick),                      bgcolor = color.new(color.green, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 4, 1, str.tostring(((ath / close) - 1) * 100 , "#.##") + "%", bgcolor = color.new(color.green, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 5, 1, str.tostring(ath - close , format.mintick),             bgcolor = color.new(color.green, transp = 50))
    
    if (show_atl)
        // ATL
        table.cell(ATHtable, 0, 2, "ATL",                                                  bgcolor = #cccccc)
        table.cell(ATHtable, 1, 2, atl_time,                                               bgcolor = color.new(color.red, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 2, 2, str.tostring(atl_days),                                 bgcolor = color.new(color.red, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 3, 2, str.tostring(atl, format.mintick),                      bgcolor = color.new(color.red, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 4, 2, str.tostring(((atl / close) - 1) * 100 , "#.##") + "%", bgcolor = color.new(color.red, transp = 50))
        table.cell(ATHtable, 5, 2, str.tostring(atl - close, format.mintick),              bgcolor = color.new(color.red, transp = 50))

// alerts
alertcondition(ta.crossover(high, ath), 'All-time High!', 'All-time High!')
alertcondition(ta.crossunder(low, atl), 'All-time Low!',  'All-time Low!')
```

[image: Example on weekly chart]
**After a few months, recent ATH will be considered by script for breakout, not old one**

Comment: So, in total, you want to have only one ATH that is at least one year old? Or do you want to have ATH for each year?

Comment: @vitruvius Sir I want it to ignore the recent ATH (if any) and show me ATH that is at least more than 1 year back! A stock may keep making ATH everyday, the old point from where breakout originally occured is more important to me, hope u understood. I have attached a pic that shows the gui (Objective is to catch breakout that has occurred after long period of time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("Previous Year(s) ATH", overlay = true)

num_years = input.int(1, title = "Number of years back", minval = 1)

var float ATH = high
var int ATH_time = time

var float[] ATH_vals = array.new_float()
var int[] ATH_time_vals = array.new_int()
var int[] ATH_time_change_vals = array.new_int()

ATH := math.max(ATH, high)
if ta.change(ATH) != 0
    ATH_time := time
    
array.unshift(ATH_vals, ATH)
array.unshift(ATH_time_vals, time)
array.unshift(ATH_time_change_vals, ATH_time)

var float ATH1Y = na

if barstate.isconfirmed
    search_time = time - 31536000000 * num_years
    for i = 0 to array.size(ATH_time_vals) - 1
        if array.get(ATH_time_vals, i) < search_time
            ATH1Y := array.get(ATH_vals, i)
            ATH1Y_time = array.get(ATH_time_change_vals, i)
            y = year(ATH1Y_time)
            m = month(ATH1Y_time)
            d = dayofmonth(ATH1Y_time)
            days_ago = (time - ATH1Y_time) / 86400000
            date_text = str.tostring(y) + "/" + str.tostring(m) + "/" + str.tostring(d) + " : " + str.tostring(ATH1Y) + "\nDays Ago : " + str.tostring(math.round(days_ago, 2))

            if ATH > ATH1Y and ATH[1] <= ATH1Y[1]
                label.new(x = bar_index[1], y = ATH[1], text = date_text, style = label.style_label_lower_right)
            break

ATH_val = ATH > ATH1Y ? na : ATH1Y

buy_signal = ATH > ATH1Y and ATH[1] <= ATH1Y[1]

plotshape(buy_signal, color = color.green, location = location.belowbar, size = size.small, style = shape.triangleup)

plot(ATH_val, title = "ATH", style = plot.style_linebr)
```

Comment: near to exactly what I needed! just one last thing left, the plot should show where the high is same for an extended period that is when price is forming new ATH daily it should not plot on those days!

Comment: `plot(ATH > ATH1Y ? na : ATH1Y)`

Comment: I am asking alot but can I get a green arrow where the ATH lines end (buy signal)  and the days ago is calculated where the ATH line is ending, not today @rumpypumpydumpy

Comment: plotshape(ATH > ATH1Y ? na : ATH1Y, style=shape.arrowup,
                 location=location.belowbar, color=color.yellow, show_last = 1, offset = 1, size=size.large)

Comment: Not quite, I've updated the answer for you.

Comment: You're amazing :D
Ps- How did you learn pinescript? let me know if you did a particular course

Comment: If you are free, you can help me with another challenge!
It should show target (vertical line from breakout to target price) 
target = (ATH - Low) of the respective periods

Comment: or u can lead me

Answer (score 1):

You can create a time window where you want to update your calculations. In the below example, it will only calculate the ATH, if the time is between 1970 and 21.11.2020 (exactly one year ago).

It should do what you are looking for. There are some user inputs, so you can be more flexible:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

ToMonth   = input.int(defval = 11, title = "To Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
ToDay     = input.int(defval = 21, title = "To Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
ToYear    = input.int(defval = 2020, title = "To Year")

start     = timestamp(1970, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00)
finish    = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 00, 00, 00)
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false

var float ath = 0.0

if window() == true
    ath := high > ath ? high : ath

var line athLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.both)

if barstate.islast
    line.set_xy1(athLine, bar_index-1, ath)
    line.set_xy2(athLine, bar_index, ath)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir for the answer however I needed it with the original table, I will try to make.

Comment: finish    = timestamp(year-2, month, dayofmonth, 00, 00, 00)
this is not working, any suggestions? I want it to be dynamic